# i cant get the div show up in wordpress theme help please

Tags: php, wordpress

in a wordpress theme, i am trying to add a div line as

`<div class="safirCustomMenu">`

and to do it i modified the function file as the following but the result is unfortunately nothing php code is below, could you please tell me where i am wrong

```
function widget($args, $instance) {

    $instance['selectedMenu'];

    $selectedMenu = extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

    echo '<div class="safirCustomMenu">';

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $selectedMenu, 'container' => 'ul', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) );

    echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did this function come from?  What did it look like originally?  What changes did you make to it?  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: i dont see any error, it just doesnt output the div but site seems working fine, the function is a custom menu on the sidebar and it works all fine apart from that i cant give the style to it since i cant place my div before <ul> as you see above, all i would like to do is having the the array output within my div tags

Answer (score 0):

Never do this. remove those div from your function and following code in your functions.php file:

```
class Walker_Page_Custom extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<div class='safirCustomMenu'><ul>\n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "$indent</ul></div><!--safirCustomMenu-->\n";
}

}
```

and the call your wp_nav_menu just like this:

```
 <?php
   $navArgs = array('walker' => new Walker_Page_Custom());
   wp_nav_menu($navArgs);
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Arshad but my problem here is, this menu is admin end controlled and it puts the menu name as the class of <ul> and it is a side widget